# How to hide text but not images within it

Tags: css

I am new to all these styling things. I entered a sort of instruction note to not-at-all techy person for his blog in the post editor as how he can upload a media. I gave that the following lines.

**HTML**

`<span class="uploadmedia">Click Upload Media and Add your image</span>`

**CSS**

`.uploadmedia {
display:none;
}`

Now, I know with this class, both the text and the image within it will be hidden. The person is supposed to click anywhere in this line **Click Upload Media and Add your image** & enter an image. But only the image should show up since that line is just acting as a instruction to him as how and where should he click to upload an image. Please help me correct this code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [Nicolas Gallagher's image replacement](http://nicolasgallagher.com/another-css-image-replacement-technique/) technique. You could add the following class to your element in order to hide the text:

```
.ir {
  font: 0/0 a;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
}
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/NJYyg/)**

Comment: Thanks Hashem for your answer. yeah I thought of it, but I heard that Google does not like this and there is some browsers compatibility issues with this color: transparent; any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: @kalyan In fact the `color: transparent` is a fallback for *for browsers than don’t completely crush the text to the point of being invisible* such as Safari 4. And `font: 0/0 a;` does the trick. In addition, I've never heard about disadvantages of this method for SEO, I'll appreciate if you could provide a link to a reference.